# SQL Server MERGE command - how to trap if nothing qualified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge, dml

With this command, we can specify something like:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks > 250 THEN DELETE
```

But how do we trap if a record *didn't* qualify? For example, say stm.StudentMarks = 100? I get a syntax error if I try "ELSE".

I know this command is not typically used this way. But if it can do this, it will save me having to use a transaction, locks, and multiple SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further learning, I have concluded that the way to do this is to use views / TVFs to get the correct data set. One could get the records complying to "IF ... THEN ..." and another could get the records complying to the ELSE. It would just been running two MERGE statements, which is no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED ....... THEN ......
```

to find those rows in the source that have no equivalent in the target (based on the `ON ....` condition you've specified), or otherwise, you need to specify more / other expressions, e.g.

```
WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks <= 250 THEN .....
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this won't work. It won't trap the matched but not clause search condition predicate. I also just found out through trial and error "An action of type 'UPDATE' is not allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement." Clearly MERGE has very specific uses, and what I want goes beyond them. Transactions & locks it will have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
```

without any extra conditions, it will only trigger one when clause and since the first gets all that matched with condition the second will only get those that matched all but the condition.

Comment: There can only be 1 of each predicate type.